# MacOS zsh: segmentation fault python3 -u

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, segmentation-fault, fatal-error, tkinter-menu

My code is shown below:

```py
import faulthandler
faulthandler.enable()

import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import os
from tkinter import messagebox
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from pandas import DataFrame


import BusinessLogic 
admin=BusinessLogic.BusinessLogic() 

current_user=1001 
current_time='2022/04/16' 
class MainWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self,current_user,current_time):
        super().__init__()
        self.login_user=current_user
        self.login_time=current_time
        self.title('newdb')
        self.geometry('900x640+180+80')
        self.resizable(height=None,width=None)
        self['bg']='skyblue'
        self.setup_UI()
    
    def setup_UI(self):
       
        menubar=tk.Menu(self)
        menu_sub=tk.Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
        menubar.add_cascade(label='book management',menu=menu_sub)
        menu_sub.add_command(label='book maintain',command=self.manage_bookGUI)
        menu_sub.add_command(label='book statics',command=self.sta_bookGUI)
        menu_sub.add_separator()
        menu_sub.add_command(label='quit',command=self.quit)
 
        help=tk.Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
        help.add_command(label='About')
        menubar.add_cascade(label='help',menu=help)
        self.config(menu=menubar)
        
        #self.searchBtn=tk.Button(self,text='book maintain',command=self.manage_bookGUI)
        #self.searchBtn.place(x=0,y=0)
        #self.searchBtn=tk.Button(self,text='book statics',command=self.sta_bookGUI)
        #self.searchBtn.place(x=200,y=0)
        self.iconbitmap('~/Documents/programme/pythonProject/graduate/learning/copy/pic/member.ico')

        self.Style01=Style()
        self.Style01.configure('left.TPanedwindow',background='skyblue')
        self.Style01.configure('right.TPanedwindow',background='skyblue')
        self.Style01.configure('TButton',width=10)

self.Login_image=PhotoImage(file='~/Documents/programme/pythonProject/graduate/learning/copy/pic/Airport.png')
        self.Label_image=Label(self,image=self.Login_image)
        self.Label_image.pack()
        self.Label_login_user=Label(self,text='user'+str(self.login_user).title()+'\nloadtime:'+self.login_time)
        self.Label_login_user.place(x=700,y=40)

        self.Pane_left=PanedWindow(width=400,height=540,style='left.TPanedwindow')
        self.Pane_leftGUI()
        self.Pane_left1=PanedWindow(width=400,height=540,style='left.TPanedwindow')
        self.Pane_leftGUI_stabook()
        self.Pane_right=PanedWindow(width=400,height=540,style='right.TPanedwindow')
        self.Pane_rightGUI()

    def Pane_leftGUI(self): 
        self.LabelFrame_query=LabelFrame(self.Pane_left,text='book search',width=400,height=70)
        self.LabelFrame_query.place(x=10,y=0)

        self.Label_snosearch=Label(self.LabelFrame_query,text='bookcode：')
        self.Label_snosearch.place(x=5,y=13)
        self.Entry_snosearch=Entry(self.LabelFrame_query,width=8)
        self.Entry_snosearch.place(x=50,y=10)

        self.Button_query=Button(self.LabelFrame_query,text='search',command=self.search_book,width=4)
        self.Button_query.place(x=220,y=10)
        self.Button_all=Button(self.LabelFrame_query,text='search all',command=self.search_allbook,width=8)
        self.Button_all.place(x=290,y=10)

        self.Tree=Treeview(self.Pane_left,columns=('sno','names'),show='headings',height=20)
        self.Tree.column('sno',width=195,anchor='center')
        self.Tree.column('names',width=195,anchor='center')
        self.Tree.heading('sno',text='bookcode')
        self.Tree.heading('names',text='bookname')
        self.Tree.place(x=10,y=73)

        self.Tree.bind('<Double-1>',self.view_book)
        self.LabelFrame_query1=LabelFrame(self.Pane_left,text='book management',width=400,height=70)
        self.LabelFrame_query1.place(x=10,y=450)

        self.Label_sno=Label(self.LabelFrame_query1,text='bookcode:')
        self.Label_sno.place(x=5,y=13)
        self.Entry_sno=Entry(self.LabelFrame_query1,width=8)
        self.Entry_sno.place(x=50,y=10)
        self.Label_name=Label(self.LabelFrame_query1,text='bookname:')
        self.Label_name.place(x=125,y=13)
        self.Entry_name=Entry(self.LabelFrame_query1,width=8)
        self.Entry_name.place(x=170,y=10)
        self.Button_add=Button(self.LabelFrame_query1,text='add',command=self.add_book,style='TButton',width=4)
        self.Button_add.place(x=240,y=10)
        self.Button_update=Button(self.LabelFrame_query1,text='update',command=self.update_book,style='TButton',width=4)
        self.Button_update.place(x=290,y=10)
        self.Button_delete=Button(self.LabelFrame_query1,text='delete',command=self.delete_book,style='TButton',width=4)
        self.Button_delete.place(x=340,y=10)

    def Pane_leftGUI_stabook(self): 
        self.LabelFrame_query1=LabelFrame(self.Pane_left1,text='book statics',width=400,height=70)
        self.LabelFrame_query1.place(x=10,y=0)

        self.Tree1=Treeview(self.Pane_left1,columns=('sno','names'),show='headings',height=20)
    
        self.Tree1.column('sno',width=195,anchor='center')
        self.Tree1.column('names',width=195,anchor='center')

        self.Tree1.heading('sno',text='bookname')
        self.Tree1.heading('names',text='booknumber')

        self.Tree1.place(x=10,y=73)

    def Pane_rightGUI(self):
        self.figure_1=plt.figure(figsize=(4,5)) 
        self.ax=self.figure_1.add_subplot(1,1,1) 
        self.canvas_1=FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure_1,self.Pane_right)

    def load_treeview(self,current_list:list,tree:Treeview):
        if len(current_list)==0:
            messagebox.showinfo(title='newdb',message='the info does not exist')
        else:
            for index in range(len(current_list)):
                tree.insert('',index,values=(current_list[index][0],current_list[index][1]))
    def clear_treeview(self,tree:Treeview):
        for item in tree.get_children():
            tree.delete(item)

    def search_book(self):
        book=admin.book_getbyID(self.Entry_snosearch.get())
        self.clear_treeview(self.Tree)
        self.load_treeview(book,self.Tree)
    def search_allbook(self):
        book=admin.book_getall()
        self.clear_treeview(self.Tree)
        self.load_treeview(book,self.Tree)

    def add_book(self):
        result=admin.book_insert(self.Entry_sno.get(),self.Entry_name.get())
        if result=='OK':
            self.clear_treeview(self.Tree)
            book=admin.book_getall()
            self.load_treeview(book,self.Tree)
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo(title='newdb',message=result)
    def update_book(self):
        result=admin.book_update(self.Entry_sno.get(),self.Entry_name.get())
        if result=='OK':
            self.clear_treeview(self.Tree)
            book=admin.book_getall()
            self.load_treeview(book,self.Tree)
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo(title='newdb',message=result)
    def delete_book(self):
        result=admin.book_delete(self.Entry_sno.get())
        if result=='OK':
            self.clear_treeview(self.Tree)
            book=admin.book_getall()
            self.load_treeview(book,self.Tree)
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo(title='newdb',message=result)

    def view_book(self,event): 
        self.action_flag=1
        item=self.Tree.selection()[0] 
        Temp_publisher_list=self.Tree.item(item,'values') 
        self.Entry_sno.delete(0,END)
        self.Entry_name.delete(0,END)
        self.Entry_sno.insert(0,Temp_publisher_list[0])
        self.Entry_name.insert(1,Temp_publisher_list[1])

    def sta_book_sort(self):
        result=admin.book_sort_sta()
        if result:
            self.clear_treeview(self.Tree1)
            self.load_treeview(result,self.Tree1)
        self.Pane_right.place(x=410,y=95)
        self.ax.clear() 
        df=DataFrame([list(i) for i in result],columns=['type','number']) 
        df.index=df['type']
        df.plot(kind='bar',fontsize='small',rot=0,ax=self.ax)
        plt.title('total book',fontsize=12)
        plt.xlabel('type',fontsize=9)
        plt.ylabel('number',fontsize=9)
        self.canvas_1.draw()
        self.canvas_1.get_tk_widget().pack()

    def manage_bookGUI(self):
        self.Pane_left1.place_forget()
        self.Pane_left.place(x=4,y=95)
        self.Pane_right.place_forget()

    def sta_bookGUI(self):
        self.Pane_left.place_forget()
        self.Pane_left1.place(x=4,y=95)
        self.Pane_right.place(x=410,y=95)
        self.sta_book_sort()

    def quit(self):
        self.destroy()
```

The all I know is that after tk interface pops up, when I click the menubar I set, the interface will exit, and python will report the following error:

```
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x000000010a8d1e00 (most recent call first):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1458 in mainloop
  File "/Users/apple/Documents/programme/pythonProject/graduate/learning/copy/tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 66 in <module>

Extension modules: numpy.core._multiarray_umath, numpy.core._multiarray_tests, numpy.linalg._umath_linalg, numpy.fft._pocketfft_internal, numpy.random._common, numpy.random.bit_generator, numpy.random._bounded_integers, numpy.random._mt19937, numpy.random.mtrand, numpy.random._philox, numpy.random._pcg64, numpy.random._sfc64, numpy.random._generator, matplotlib._c_internal_utils, PIL._imaging, matplotlib._path, kiwisolver._cext, matplotlib._image, matplotlib.backends._tkagg, pandas._libs.tslibs.dtypes, pandas._libs.tslibs.base, pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime, pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype, pandas._libs.tslibs.timezones, pandas._libs.tslibs.ccalendar, pandas._libs.tslibs.tzconversion, pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime, pandas._libs.tslibs.fields, pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas, pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps, pandas._libs.properties, pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets, pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing, pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion, pandas._libs.tslibs.period, pandas._libs.tslibs.vectorized, pandas._libs.ops_dispatch, pandas._libs.missing, pandas._libs.hashtable, pandas._libs.algos, pandas._libs.interval, pandas._libs.tslib, pandas._libs.lib, pandas._libs.hashing, pandas._libs.ops, pandas._libs.arrays, pandas._libs.index, pandas._libs.join, pandas._libs.sparse, pandas._libs.reduction, pandas._libs.indexing, pandas._libs.internals, pandas._libs.writers, pandas._libs.window.aggregations, pandas._libs.window.indexers, pandas._libs.reshape, pandas._libs.groupby, pandas._libs.testing, pandas._libs.parsers, pandas._libs.json, PIL._imagingtk (total: 61)
zsh: segmentation fault  python3 -u
```

But there is no problem when I replace 'menubar' with 'button'. But I hope to be able to successfully use 'menubar' in tk, so how can I improve my code?

Comment: Try removing pieces of the code that don't effect the error. That way the code will be simpler to read and the error might become obvious. Also does this only happen when you run your code using `ptyon3` with the `-u` option?

Comment: I have no idea, sometimes the same code runs without errors, but most of the time it will be reported like this, this is also what bothers me.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).